# preg_match from beginning of array to backward slash

Tags: php, preg-match

Could someone explain how to use php `preg_match` to break a string up into an array, from the beginning of the string to the first backward slash?

I have an array:

```
(
    [0] => s00473276\Soul To Squeeze\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [1] => t00034422\Soul To Squeeze\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [2] => 209676\Soul To Squeeze\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [3] => s00473331\What Is Soul ?\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [4] => 209672\Show Me Your Soul\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [5] => t00034415\Show Me Your Soul\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [6] => s00473268\Show Me Your Soul\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [7] => s00473233\Out Of Range By Red Hot Chili Peppers\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [8] => 209603\Get On Top\Red Hot Chili Peppers
    [9] => t00034374\I've Been Down\Red Hot Chili Peppers
)
```

And I want to create another array so I will be left with

```
[0] => s00473276
[1] => t00034422 etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$new_array = array();
foreach($your_array as $element)
  list($new_array[]) = explode('\\', $element);

print_r($new_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Easiest / "cleanest" (warning: subjective) solution is probably [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
<?php

$array = array('s00473276\Soul To Squeeze\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
               't00034422\Soul To Squeeze\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
               '209676\Soul To Squeeze\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
               's00473331\What Is Soul ?\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
               '209672\Show Me Your Soul\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
               't00034415\Show Me Your Soul\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
               's00473268\Show Me Your Soul\Red Hot Chili Peppers',
);

function myFunc($item) {
        $parts = explode('\\', $item, 2);

        return $parts[0];
}

$newArray = array_map('myFunc', $array);

print_r($newArray);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => s00473276
    [1] => t00034422
    [2] => 209676
    [3] => s00473331
    [4] => 209672
    [5] => t00034415
    [6] => s00473268
)
```

([demo](http://ideone.com/o80GQ))

Comment: Two minutes and still nothing :-)

Comment: @JanTuroň Sorry :) Ideone was slooow ... and so was my brain.

Answer (score 2):

Why `preg_match()`? Using `substr()` along with `array_map()` will be faster.

```
array_map('f', $array);

function f($s)
{
  return substr($s, 0, strpos($s, '\\'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
$arr = array();
foreach($yourArray as $key => $value){
  $split = explode('\\', $value);
  $arr[$key] = $split[0];
}

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm using this correctly, Is the only thing I need to input $yourArray? I got an error:
Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 on line 20 ($split = explode('\', $value);

    Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1  on line 20

    Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1  on line 20

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'  on line 20

Comment: @LearningDaily: Your array contains \ or / ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$input  = array( /* your data */ );
$output = array();
foreach ( $input as $value ) {
  $output[] = str_split($value, 0, substr($value, '/'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with preg_match

```
$result = array();
foreach ($a as $value) {
    preg_match("#([^\\\\]*)\\\\#", $value, $match);
    $result[] = $match[1];
}
```